# Which of the following options are correct about $X = \left \{C \in GL_3 (\Bbb R)\ |\ CAC^{-1}\ \text {is triangular} \right \}\ $?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, jordan-normal-form, triangularization

> Let $A \in M_3 (\Bbb R)$ and let $X = \left \{C \in GL_3 (\Bbb R)\ |\ CAC^{-1}\ \text {is triangular} \right \}.$ Then

> $(1)$ $X \neq \varnothing$

> $(2)$ If $X = \varnothing,$ then $A$ is not diagonalisable over $\Bbb C$

> $(3)$ If $X = \varnothing,$ then $A$ is diagonalisable over $\Bbb C$

> $(4)$ If $X = \varnothing,$ then $A$ has no real eigenvalue

**My attempt** $:$ $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(4)$ are definitely false. For instance we may consider the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$ Now if $X = \varnothing$ that implies there exists at least one eigenvalue of $A$ which is non-real for otherwise we can transform $A$ to it's real Jordan canonical form which is upper triangular and hence $X \neq \varnothing,$ a contradiction to our hypothesis. How does that imply that $A$ is diagonalizable over $\Bbb C\ $? Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If $X=\emptyset$ then as you have argued, $A$ has three different eigenvalues: one real, two not real but conjugate to each other.

Comment: So all three eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct and hence $A$ is diagonalizable over $\Bbb C.$ Am I right @daw?

Comment: Done it! Thanks. I forgot that it's a $3 \times 3$ matrix? I initially thought it for $n \times n$ matrix.